# Azure Logic Apps-Download File from URL

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a requirement in Logic Apps where I need to do HTTP GET from a website URL which gives a file which I need to download to Azure File Storage.

I am able to call the downloadable URL but not sure how to go about downloading the file to Azure File storage directory.

Please let me know your inputs.Do I need to write an Azure function or can I get the HTTP action to do the trick to download the file?

Thanks,

SP

Comment: I think you'll have to write an Azure Function

Comment: thank you could you please share the code for Azure Function and when i call the Downloadble URL ,how to get the file content to be passed to azure function.thanks sp

Comment: Sorry but this is not how it works here. Try to code something and if you have a problem, ask a question ;-)

Comment: Can this be done all in a logic app? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57829510/how-do-i-create-a-logic-app-to-copy-pictures-from-slack-channel

Answer (score 4):

I suppose Logic apps has moved on a little since you first asked this question.

The short answer is yes you can do this solely within Logic Apps.

I'm assuming you're making a HTTP Request at some point and the downloadable file is being returned as a content type of application/octet

Use a 'Blob Storage'->Create Blob action, the only thing I needed to do was to use the binary function as the content in this action

e.g. binary(body('HTTP'))

This caused my zip file to be created in the Azure storage account as a blob.

Ping me if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to **create one web api function or azure funtion which return file content** like i tried for zip file

2) You need to **call that method using HTTP connector**

3) You can use **"azure File storage"** connector **"create file"** action

in that you need to pass file and **file content which return from your GET API Url**

if you need more help feel free to ask