# How do I create a logic app to copy pictures from slack channel?

Tags: slack, azure-logic-apps

I want to automate copying pictures that arrive in a slack channel to go to an Azure Blob.

I found [some docs on connecting to Slack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-slack)
and was able to create a When File Is Created task

The next thing I tried was a Copy blob step.  However this does not seem right.

[image: logic app picture]

[Update]

From George's help I added the HTTP task.

Here is what I see in the code view of the Slack trigger

> [image: trigger]

or in modified text format

```
    {
    "$connections": {
        "value": {
            "slack_1": {
                "connectionId": "/subscriptions/subscriptionid/resourceGroups/SlackPicToBlob/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/slack-1",
                "connectionName": "slack-1",
                "id": "/subscriptions/subscriptionid/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/australiasoutheast/managedApis/slack"
            }
        }
    },
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {},
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_file_is_created": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['slack_1']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/trigger/files.list",
                    "queries": {
                        "channel": "CMRUVPHS5"
                    }
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()",
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Update]

I ran the task and now understand George's instruction to create the link using the menu in Slack.

After creating the link I get the following error.

```
No output
```

> [image: No output]

Looking at a run history, the HTTP Raw inputs are

```
{
    "uri": "https://files.slack.com/files-pri/TMLT14MDH-FN842SZD3/img_20190911_175347.jpg?pub_secret=3b49994016",
    "method": "GET"
}
```

and the raw outputs are

```
{
    "statusCode": 302,
    "headers": {
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "X-Backend": "supra-prod-syd-7d7dc657-m6t8j",
        "X-Slack-Meta": "?;proxy_redir",
        "X-Cache": "Miss from cloudfront",
        "X-Amz-Cf-Pop": "MEL50",
        "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "T8AsYDMMGWkO12pi97bvgfJzkxjXu5F_4cMOalyH9NQutxEpi8OseQ==",
        "Date": "Wed, 11 Sep 2019 07:56:13 GMT",
        "Location": "https://jobtalk-workspace.slack.com/?redir=%2Ffiles-pri%2FTMLT14MDH-FN842SZD3%2Fimg_20190911_175347.jpg%3Fpub_secret%3D3b49994016",
        "Via": "1.1 2f3f099f90ecec674faf8faec5c60de1.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
        "Content-Length": "152",
        "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    },
    "body": "<a href=\"https://jobtalk-workspace.slack.com/?redir=%2Ffiles-pri%2FTMLT14MDH-FN842SZD3%2Fimg_20190911_175347.jpg%3Fpub_secret%3D3b49994016\">Found</a>.\n\n"
}
```

The Create blob tasks shows the error message

> ActionConditionFailed. The execution of template action 'Create_blob'
>   is skipped: the 'runAfter' condition for action 'HTTP' is not
>   satisfied. Expected status values 'Succeeded' and actual value
>   'Failed'.

The Create blob tasks shows the error message

> ActionConditionFailed. The execution of template action 'Create_blob'
>   is skipped: the 'runAfter' condition for action 'HTTP' is not
>   satisfied. Expected status values 'Succeeded' and actual value
>   'Failed'.

[Update]

After I created the external link I was able to get the tasks passing.
However the blob did not arrive in storage.

[image: Make blob]

I expect I need a step to download the file.

I am following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311455/azure-logic-apps-download-file-from-url) for help on that.

Comment: Please post the code rather than the screenshot of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not create a blob with the slack trigger because the trigger response doesn't contain the file, check the [slack trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/slack/#when-a-file-is-created) you will find it only return some file information and some links. It will be like the below picture.

[image]

So you have to use a HTTP GET action to get the picture from the link. And this doesn't return the external link(Cause the external link won't be created by default), so you also need create external link after upload the file.

[image]

And the default external link is combined with url_private and the pub_secret in permalink_public, so the HTTP GET url input will be like this

`@{triggerBody()['url_private']}?pub_secret=@{substring(triggerBody()['permalink_public'],44,10)}`

So my flow is like the below picture, you could have a try, if you still have problem please feel free to let me know.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How do i see the return information of the slack trigger? ( i.e your first screen shot)

Comment: @Kirsten Greed, it's the run history output, pick one history you want to check, then select the action and click show raw outputs. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmZlf.png

Comment: @Kirsten Greed, could you get the picture now? Or any update?

Comment: The app detects that a picture has been placed in the slack chanel but the HTTP Get fails. How do I get the menu to creat the external link?  I need more information about that.

Comment: There are two way, in the channel,one directly from the picture, choose [more actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHSpi.png) then click [create external link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmYSO.png) or go to view channel detail under shared files choose the picture the [create external link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zeJk.png).

Comment: Thanks, I see how to create an external link in Slack now. However even if I know how to automate that I dont see how it helps me.

Comment: @Kirsten Greed, only create the external link then the HTTP request link in my answer will work, it will get the image and you will be able to create the blob.

Comment: @Kirsten Greed, please show what error it shows or the HTTP action run details and the HTTP url what expression you use.

Comment: I updated the question. Is that what you mean by the expression I use?

Comment: It will get error it's because the logic app is already triggered before you create the external link, then the HTTP couldn't get the image from the link, so immediately create the external link after you upload the image.

Comment: Thanks George. The file still does not make it to the blob for some reason. Even though all 3 tasks get a green tick.... but I think that would be a new question to solve.

Comment: Yes, the best is ask a new answer. And what blob action you are using, I used create blob it could work.

Comment: I used create blob too.

Comment: What's your blob content expression? And you mean it couldn't create the blob, or create the damage blob file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199307/discussion-between-kirsten-greed-and-george-chen).